# ListOperator usage in methods

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I dont know how can I share all my codes or classes to explain what's wrong. But I'm gonna try with this little part.  I have Linkedlist which is Video type. And I want to play next vid. With this method. In a switch- case loop.

```
    public static void playTheList (LinkedList<Video> video) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Choice: ");
    int choice= sc.nextInt();
    boolean out = false;

    while (!out) {
    switch(choice){
    case 1:
    if(iterator.hasNext()){
    Video firstVideo=iterator.next();
    System.out.println("****");
    System.out.println(" Playing video Name :"+firstVideo.getVideoName()+" Video length: "+firsVideo.getVideoLenghth());

    }
    else{
    System.out.println("End of List");
    }
    break;

    case 2:
    playNextVid(videoList);
    break;
    
    case 3:
    out=true;
    break;
    }
    }
    }
```

Everytime when I press "1 " I want to see next element of LinkedList  till end of list. The problem is when i do the iterations thing in switch-case loop, it works. But when i try to create new method and tried to call that method. The methods works and finishes in that scope so doesn't remember where was the iteration. So It doesn't work. Case 1 is works, case 2 doesnt work. How can I fix this? And I hope you can understand what's wrong. Sorry for english.

```
    public static void playNextVid(LinkedList<Video> video){

    ListIterator<Videos> iterator=video.listIterator();

    if(iterator.hasNext()){
    Video firstVideo=iterator.next();
    System.out.println("****");
    System.out.println(" Playing video Name :"+firstVideo.getVideoName()+" Video length: "+firstVideo.getVideoLenghth());

    }
    else{
    System.out.println("End of List");

    }
    }
```

Comment: `playNextVid(LinkedList<Video> video)` → `playNextVid(ListIterator<Video> iterator)`

Comment: First, switch is not a loop so there must be some loop around your case statement that you're not showing.  Second, there is no loop in your method so it's only showing the first element.  Can you describe exactly what problem you have?

Comment: I've tried to update. If you don't mind you can check. @DaveS

Comment: Every time you call the method you are constructing a new iterator.  When you construct a new iterator it always starts at the first element.  In case 2 you should pass the iterator to the method rather than passing the linked list and constructing a new iterator on every call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how can I share all my codes or classes to explain what's
> wrong.

There is no need. You should post an [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like the following:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        List<String> video = Arrays.asList("video S01E01", "video S01E02","video S01E03", "video S01E04");
        Iterator<String> iterator = video.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; i <= video.size(); i++) {
            handleChoice(iterator, 2);
        }
    }

    private static void handleChoice(Iterator<String> iterator, int choice){
         switch(choice){
            case 1:
                if(iterator.hasNext()){
                    System.out.println(" Playing video Name :"+iterator.next());
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("End of List");
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                playNextVid(iterator);
                break;
         }
    }

    private static void playNextVid(Iterator<String> iterator) {

           if(iterator.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(" Playing video Name :"+iterator.next());
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("End of List");
            }
    }
}
```